# How to partially apply a function to yield a polymorphic rank-1 type?

Tags: haskell, partial-application, automatic-differentiation, rank-n-types

I want to partially apply a function `f :: T` to a value `x :: [Double]` to get a resulting function `f' :: forall a . Floating a => [a] -> a`. What should `T` be? I can't figure it out.

One difficulty is that, inside `f`, I need to combine `x :: [Double]` with the first parameter of `f'` (let's call it `y`) via some math (e.g. adding each element of the lists).

I know that internally, `x` and `y` will both be `Double`s, so I ended up using the type `f :: forall a . Floating a => [a] -> (forall b . Floating b => [b] -> b)`, and using `unsafeCoerce` (I know, I know...) inside `f` whenever a value of type `a` is combined with type `b`.

Any thoughts on a better type for `f`?

Context: I'm forced to produce the more general `forall a . Floating a => [a] -> a` type after partially applying `f` because I need to take the gradient of the resulting function using the Haskell autodiff library `ad`. The function `grad` in that library requires that its input function have that general type.

(Why do I need to partially apply an objective function? You can imagine that such a function would have internal constants that should not be treated by the optimizer as part of a changing state vector. A hack might be to treat the constants as part of the state and just not update the constants, but in that case the norm of the gradient wouldn't go to zero at the local minima, and other things might go wrong.)

Comment: What is the library your are using? I suspect there is some terrible misunderstanding here - this looks much more complicated than it should be. :)

Comment: For autodiff, this library: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad You can find the type of `grad` here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad-4.3.2.1/docs/Numeric-AD.html (and I certainly hope the problem is easier than I think it is!)

Comment: Well, why don't you simply use `realToFrac` to generalize the input? `:t map realToFrac [1.0 :: Double, 2.0, 3.0]  :: Fractional b => [b]` so when you partially apply `f` instead of doing `f listOfDoubles` you could do `f (map realToFrac listOfDoubles)`.

Comment: @Bakuriu thanks, that worked! I didn't know that function existed. Guess I should've Hoogled more thoroughly :-)

Comment: Is there any reason to specifically include the `forall` keywords in the type contexts? I thought those were implicit.

Comment: Yes, it's implicit, but I wanted to emphasize the `forall` because it becomes explicit when I need to accept a function containing a `forall` as an argument to another function (as in the type of `f`).